# Data restructuring into panel format - extract cell values across columns

Tags: r, data-manipulation

In short:
What I have:

```r
  id year1 year2 year3 size1 size2 size3
   1  2000  2007  2009    50    80   100
   2  2002  2004    NA   100   110    NA
```

What I want:

```r
id  y2000   y2001   y2002   y2003   y2004   y2005   y2006   y2007   y2008   y2009
1      50      50      50      50      50      50      50      80      80     100
2      NA      NA     100     100     110     110     110     110     110     110
```

I need to restructure my data into a panel format, where I have two sets of columns. One set contains random years, the other set contains the corresponding size. In the end I'd like to get a standard table format with year columns containing the corresponding size. Additionally, subsequent years after an entry should contain the former value until there is an "update". E.g.: For id=1 the final table should contain the value 50 between 2000 and 2006, then in 2007 it gets the value 80, etc.

```
mydata <- data.frame("id"=c(1,2),  "year1"=c(2000,2002),    "year2"=c(2007,2004),
                     "year3"=c(2009,NA),    "size1"=c(50,100),  "size2"=c(80,110),
                     "size3"=c(100,NA))             


years <- paste("y", 2000:2009, sep="")
mydata[years] <- NA


opy <- c("year1", "year2", "year3")
ops <- c("size1", "size2", "size3")


ifelse (mydata[opy]==substring(names(mydata[years]),first=2,last=5),
        apply(mydata[years], 2, function(x) x <- mydata[ops]), NA)
```

I  see that this can't work, but unfortunately I really can't wrap my head around this. There is no error message - it simply does not do want I want it to do.

I am trying to get this data.frame:

```r
mydatanew <- data.frame("id"=c(1,2),    "y2000"=c(50,NA), "y2001"=c(50,NA),
                        "y2002"=c(50,100),  "y2003"=c(50,100),
                        "y2004"=c(50,110),  "y2005"=c(50,110),
                        "y2006"=c(50,110),  "y2007"=c(80,110),
                        "y2008"=c(80,110),  "y2009"=c(100,110))
```

Comment: Just Post a snapshot of input data and output data. This will help in understanding the problem. You can also try `melt` and `dcast` functions.

Comment: What do you mean by snapshot?

Comment: In your question, you have not added how the input data looks(its just in code, which needs to be printed in R. Also output does is very hard to read. It apears that you are also trying to fill some blank or missing value. For example for Id 1, you dont have data for year 2001, but in your output, you have given it value 50(same value as year 2000). Please add some explanation about this too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using package `tidyr`:

```
library(tidyverse)
mydata %>%
  gather("key", "value", -id, na.rm=T) %>% 
  extract(key, into=c("base_var", "rank"), regex="([a-zA-Z]*)(\\d*)") %>% 
  spread(base_var, value) %>% 
  select(-rank) %>% 
  complete(id, year=full_seq(year, 1)) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  fill(size) %>% 
  mutate(year=paste0("y", year)) %>% 
  spread(year, size)
```

To understand better what each step is doing, I suggest you execute only the first *x* steps, by restricting the instruction to everything before the *x* th pipe (`%>%`)